# Maximum Pooling Size for Database Connection

Tags: database, postgresql, connection-pooling, connection-timeout

I have a error as '**Timeout while getting a connection from pool**' which solved by add "MaxPoolSize" key in connection string value an increase its value to be more than 150, The questions here.

1. what is the drawback for increasing this value ?
2. what is the maximum value i can set "If it depends on anythings please give me an example with values"?

*.i.e. For these givens (1..2..3..) maxpoolSize should be between 100 -150*

**My Application**
.net frame work 3.5 and PostgreSQL version 9.6 and npgsql version 2.0.11

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What connection pooler are you using?

Comment: @jjanes if you mean connection pooler like PGPOOL or Pgbouncer i dont use any one of them i just add MaxpoolSize in my connection string only.